# How can I gzinflate and save the inflated data without running it? (Found what I think is a trojan on my server)

Tags: php, eval, base64, gzip

Well, not my server. My friend found it and sent it to me, trying to make sense of it. What it appears to be is a PHP IRC bot, but I have no idea how to decode it and make any sense of it.

Here is the code:

`<?eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('some base 64 code here')))?>`

So I decoded the base64, and it output a ton of strange characters, I'm guessing either encrypted or a different file type, like when you change a .jpg to a .txt and open it.

But I have no idea how to decode this and determine its source. Any help?

Comment: Be aware that source code is likely to be obfuscated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be safe, but still show you the code:

```
<pre>
<?echo(gzinflate(base64_decode('some base 64 code here')))?>
</pre>
```

That is, `echo` instead of `eval`.

If you'd rather do it in the shell, try `gunzip` after base64 decoding.

Comment: This worked, but, it seemed to parse HTML instead of just showing me the code. Is there a way to make it NOT parse the HTML?

Comment: Right... then you need to wrap it in <pre> tags.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Ah worked perfectly, thank you. Turns out it was a php backdoor, not an IRC bot.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll probably find is that the eval produces another cycle to eval. This may go on until finally the real code gets executed.

I would decode it step by step on a network disconnected machine which afterwards I would format.

Comment: I used legoscia's answer on a virtual box disconnected from the net. :)