# gzinflate erroring

Tags: php

Well, I'm trying to gzdeflate my code to perform some very low level encryption for distribution, to use with `eval(gzinflate('deflated_code'));`

However whenever I try to inflate the deflated string, it outputs an error.

For example:

`echo(gzdeflate('test'));` outputs `+I-.�`

But when I try to `echo(gzinflate('+I-.�'));` it only outputs `Warning: gzinflate() [function.gzinflate]: data error`

Is there something I'm missing? Why is it outputting this error rather than `test`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of

```
$s = gzdeflate('test');
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($s); $i++) {
  printf("%02X ", ord($s[$i]));
}
```

is `2B 49 2D 2E 01 00`. The last two bytes  01 00 are in this case the tricky part.
You used `echo` to print the result "string". What was the output medium?
When I copy the string `+I-.�` via ultraedit into the script the output is `2B 49 2D 2E 3F`. A different result and the cause for gzinflate() to bail out.

If you really have to display the data in a medium that cannot show all possible "characters" in the result of gzdeflate() you have to encode the result in a way that either those unprintable characters are avoided or encoded in a suitable form for that medium, e.g. via [base64_encode()](http://docs.php.net/base64_encode).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by medium? And how can I get the correct I guess, 'printable' string, so that i can inflate it properly? Also, I will be using base64 as well, but I also want this for additional "encryption" if I can call it that.

Comment: You used echo to send the data to something that printed the string. Where did you send it? (To an html browser like firefox?) And why did you sent it there? (Is it something a user should be able to copy&paste?). E.g. if you had saved the result of gzinflate() to a file via file_put_contents() and read it via file_get_contents() there would have been no trouble. The "problem" right now is, that there is something inbetween that **interprets** the data. And it interprets the byte sequence 01 00 different than you expect/want.

Comment: Well I've seen it used before (here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722973/how-can-i-gzinflate-and-save-the-inflated-data-without-running-it-found-what-i) and so I need to know how I can properly input the string necessary to inflate it correctly, like they did there.

Comment: Nevermind. reversed the position of base64_encode and gzdeflate, and it worked. Thanks for the help :)